# Is there any program I can use to draw in a 3D environment?

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

I recently tried out Tilt Brush (on Vive), and I'd like to try something like that.

I found out that the Grease Pencil tool works as 3D, so as you can see, I used the Grease Pencil tool on Blender to create this 3D cube on a 3D plane. Is there anything that can allow me to do something like that?

[image: 3D cube using Grease Pencil]

I asked this question over at Graphics Design stack exchange, where people told me that "You cannot draw in 3D using a 2D input".

(Please don't tell me the same, even if it's what you think it is; just tell me that I can't as of now.)

I know this, but is there any way (like the Grease Pencil) to draw in a 3D environment? I guess I can keep on using Grease Pencil, but I was wondering if there are any other programs that support this kind of feature.

EDIT: I figured out an easier way to use grease pencil to draw in 3D, this question is closed!

[image: house!]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about blender.

Comment: @batFINGER - Well then, can you recommend me as to where to post this question? I _did_ use blender in it and used it as a main point, after all..

Comment: Primarily, my hassle is with the title of your question, which leads to either "blender" as an answer, or what could be considered off-topic.   I'm sure you can rework your question .. maybe "how do i make this grease pencil cube into a mesh?"

Comment: I'm just curious about any other ways to get about this.. If what I wanted to do was making 3D models, I would just make sticks and move them around, that's easier.. XD Do you have any recommendations as to how to rework this question?

Comment: I'm confused with this question. Are you asking if other apps have a similar tool? What is wrong with using the grease pencil in blender? Do you, or don't you want to draw in a three dimensional space? Are you looking to draw flat images using the grease pencil, it can be done if you are on a fixed view. Please clarify what you mean by "an easier way to get about it" ?

Comment: @cegaton - I am asking if other apps have a similar tool, the grease pencil in blender requires you to select specific points on a 3D plane (which is difficult, because it takes a lot of tries to select exactly the point you're thinking of) I am looking to draw images on a 3D environment, (I can always draw in 2D using other programs)

Comment: if you figured an easier way to do what you want, how about posting an answer to your own question? Could become clearer what this is all about (sounds like drawing in VR to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably fascinated by what you saw was possible with Tilt Brush or some other VR painting program, but the sad truth is, you won't be able to do that without HTC Vive or something similar.

As long as we are talking about classic computer interface which has its input (mouse) provide the position in 2 dimensions, it's very difficult, at best not very practical to draw lines in 3D space. You always need some information about the 3rd dimension. I guess you could use pressure sensitive tablet or similar input methods for that 3d dimension, but drawing in a program like that would be, in best case scenario, impractical.

Blender deals with this problem pretty well. If you just open Blender and give grease pencil a try, you will see that it has 4 different stroke placement methods (partially copied from https://docs.blender.org):

1. View
   New strokes are placed in screen space (2D) and are locked to the view.

   - Like drawing on top of your screen. Doesn't change as you change your view.
2. Cursor
   New strokes are drawn in 3D-space, with the position determined by the 3D cursor and the view rotation at the time of drawing. The cursor is available as an option in the UV/Image Editor but it functions identically to the View option. (3D View only)

   - It uses 2D coordinates you give him and for the 3rd coordinate, it uses the distance of 3D cursor, measured along camera normal (your view is always a camera) from you.
     Imagine you are drawing on a plane, pivoting around the 3D cursor, that is always facing you (angle between your camera/view normal and face normal of this plane is 180°).
3. Surface
   New strokes are drawn in 3D-space, with their position projected onto the first visible surface. (3D View only)

   - Similar to the method above (Cursor). But instead of an invisible plane, it's using the geometry of the first visible surface. When you are drawing in the air, I suppose it' s using Cursor method.
4. Stroke
   New strokes are drawn in 3D-space, with their position projected onto existing visible strokes. Note that strokes created with View are not in 3D-space and are not considered for this projection. (3D View only)

   - Again, similar to above two methods, but this time, the source of the 3rd coordinate is the closest point in your previous grease pencil strokes. It's probably the least predictable and sometimes it snaps to the wrong stroke. Where there are no strokes to snap to, I suppose, again, it's using Cursor method.

Hope I was able to offer you some help. In the end, the only way you will completely understand the behavior of grease pencil is jumping into Blender and trying it for yourself.

Comment: yes! I figured out how to use the grease pencil much more easily, and now I am actually creating some very nice results! I just used a cube and moved it around to the desired position, selected one side of the cube, and drew along the selected plane. It's obviously much more difficult than something like Tilt Brush, but it's awesome nontheless! :D

Comment: Glad you achived your goal. Hope you create something awesome.

Comment: I figured it out before I saw your comment, but thanks for the insight on the grease pencil tool. And since you spent so much work on it, I'll mark it as the answer!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't post the answer sooner. I wrote the answer offline and didn't even notice your edit. Nonetheless, good luck with drawing.